# Is it possible to data-bind to a select dropdown with knockout while inside a foreach binding on a html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am trying to show the same `select` with the same values and functions on a table. I am using the `foreach` binding to bind to my table objects. Here is what my code looks like:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nextable Name</th>
            <th>POS Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: tables">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td><select  class="select2 span8 dropdown"  data-placeholder="Select Pos Table" data-bind="options: $parent.omnivoreTables, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue:'id', value: $parent.selectedOmnivoreTableId"></select></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For some reason, the dropdowns all say undefined and are not selectable at all. I inspect the page and the dropdown elements and they all have the correct options and values inside as if this worked, but it doesn't. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I see you have the `select2` class applied - are you also using the [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) library?  It's not one I've used myself, but it could be related.

Comment: It works in pure knockout: http://jsfiddle.net/sc4dwy9d/1/

Are you sure it's not something with your data? Or another library is causing this problem, as stated above.

Comment: If he is using Select2, he'll need to create a custom KOBinding to wire things up properly. It's a bit daunting, but I believe there are examples floating around the web.

Comment: Maybe look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131064/knockout-js-binding-with-multiple-select2

Comment: thanks guys, i've taken away the select2..still no luck. I saw your post Frexus...I don't understand how mine isn't working except that I am using an older version of knockout.

Comment: Please try to edit your question and include enough code to actually reproduce it. If you check the editor toolbar there's an "add snippet" feature (akin to jsfiddle) where you can also choose specific KO versions. Without a repro it's not likely we'll be able to help (without resorting to guessing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want it to do?

```js
var vm = {
  omnivoreTables: [
    {name: 'One',
     id: '1'},
    {name: 'Two',
     id: '2'}
    ],
  selectedOmnivoreTableId: ko.observable(1),
  tables: ko.observableArray([
    {name: 'First'},
    {name: 'Second'},
    {name: 'Third'}
  ])
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nextable Name</th>
      <th>POS Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: tables">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
      <td>
        <select class="span8 dropdown" data-placeholder="Select Pos Table" data-bind="options: $parent.omnivoreTables, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue:'id', value: $parent.selectedOmnivoreTableId"></select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```